# Cannot upload images in magento

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.7, admin

I have a custom module by which i am trying to upload images. However i cant upload images

This is my form file

```
<?php
    <form id="imageform" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>">
         <input type="file" id="chain_Image" value="" name="Image[]" class="input-text">
    </form>
```

note that this is only a small part of my code. actually this form can contain any number images. that is we can upload more than one image at a time.

This is my saveAction() :

```
 <?php
    $arr = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Image');
    foreach($arr as $image)
    {
       if(isset($_FILES[$image]['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name']))) 
       {             
           try 
           {
               $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'banner' . DS;
               $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($image);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg'));
               $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
               $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
               $destFile = $path.$_FILES[$image]['name'];
               filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
               $uploader->save($path, $filename);
               $postData['Image'] = $_FILES[$image]['name'];
           }
           catch(Exception $e) 
           {}
       }
       else
       {                                                      
           if(isset($postData[$image]['delete']) && $postData[$image]['delete'] == 1)
                $postData[$image] = '';
           else
                unset($postData[$image]);
       }
   }                          
   $bannerModel->addData($postData)->setId($this
                ->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->save();
```

However it does not upload my imaged. $_FILES is seem to be empty,when i have printed this. What is the problem in my code. Help me. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

Comment: nope.. i have it in my edit.php file

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a mistake at save function. Here is my example code for saving an image with other details. Let see this may help you.

```
$newsModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                                  ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                                  ->setImage($_FILES['image']['name'])
                                  ->setContent($postData['content'])
                                  ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                                  ->save();
```

You have to save the image by calling as `setImage($_FILES['image']['name'])`  Try this..

Comment: :thanks for the reply. but i have other field also to save. All other fields are working perfectly except this image uploading. can I use this code for save action then?

Comment: yes.. This code is for save action only. Place this code in try block of save action and add the other fields which u need. But the image field has to be called in the above format only.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put the  **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form parameters :

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" id="chain_Image" value="" name="Image[]" class="input-text">
    </form>
```